# Multiple Docker Containers on single server

Tags: apache, docker, liferay, containers

[image: Docker Nginx Liferay]We are planning to host  different docker containers with different liferay web applications in single Ubuntu server with static IP and point them to different websites.what is the easy setup process.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK you have two choices:

1. (Easy) Listen different port for each web application:

   `yoursite.com:8080 --> some web app
   yoursite.com:9090 --> another web app`
2. (A bit more work) Use a virtual host approach, where you have just one proxy service listening (maybe port 80). Then configure a subdomain for each of your services and point them to same server and forward the requests in proxy service according to domain names:

   `app-a.yoursite.com --> localhost:8080 --> some web app
   app-b.yoursite.com --> localhost:9090 --> another web app`